# Making Python, JS, and HTML interact with each other

Tags: javascript, python, html, interaction

I am trying to develop my fist project which is the creation of a tamagotchi.
I write my code in Python in the backend for the tamagochi behaviour, but I don't understand how to make all files interact with one another.
For instance, I coded an hunger counter that starts at 0 and each n seconds get +1.
I created a button in my HTML file for feeding.
I want my counter to go back to 0 each time people click on the button.
I don't understand how to make my various files communicate with one another.
I use Flask to make my Python and JS file communicate.
Any suggestions on how to tackle the problem (or doc that would explain it) is more than welcome.

What I expect to happen is if I press a button on my webpage, the various counter I create on the back end side in my python file (hunger, tiredness, cleanliness etc) will be reset so that the cycle can restart from 0.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.